# How to ensure that a loading belongs to a variable in PCA

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statistics, pca

I have the following piece of code which I'm using to perform PCA on my data:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
# drop the 'memberid' column
X = df[list(df.columns.difference(['memberid']))]
pca = PCA(0.80).fit(X)
Xpca = pca.transform(X)
```

Then I calculate the topmost contributing variable(s) in each principal component as follows:

```
variables = df[list(df.columns.difference(['memberid']))].columns.values
uniqueVariables = []
uniqueIndices = []
for i in range(0,len(pca.explained_variance_ratio_)):
    # Grab the variable that falls in the 95th percentile of the loadings
    indices = [k for k in range(0,len(pca.components_[i])) if abs(pca.components_[i][k]) >= np.percentile(abs(pca.components_[i]),95)]
    for j in indices:
        uniqueVariables.append(variables[j])
```

In the code above, I'm storing all the variable names in `variables`. Then I'm picking the index of the variable where the loading falling after 95th percentile (in other words, the variable(s) that contributes the most towards that principal component).

I now try to plot the loadings of each individual principal component (only 1 shown here, say, the 3rd princiapl component, identified by the index of 2):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
indices = [k for k in range(0,len(pca.components_[2])) if abs(pca.components_[2][k]) >= np.percentile(abs(pca.components_[2]), 95)]
tempdf = {'Variable': list(variables[indices]), 
          'Value'  : list(pca.components_[2][indices])}
tempdf = pd.DataFrame(tempdf)
tempdf.set_index('Variable').sort_index(ascending=False).plot(kind='barh',figsize=(5,5))
plt.show()
```

Here we can see that I'm plotting this graph based on the column names in the dataframe and the loadings of a principal component. This gives me the following graph (column names removed):

[image: Let's say the column names are A through G, for 7 variables]

Let's say the column names are A through G, for 7 variables

Here's what the loadings for this principal component look like:

```
array([ 0.43144526, -0.68946464,  0.01079084, -0.0601113 , -0.0156593 ,
       -0.02898552, -0.57764895])
```

My question is: How do I ensure that the loading value of 0.43144 belongs to `Variable A` and the loading of -0.57764 belongs to `Variable G`? I would like to make sure that the right variable is taking on the right loading.

Are there better methods to make sure that the right loading goes to the right variable in question?